# WP query works for admin roles but not for other roles

Tags: wordpress

This only works for ADMINS - when used with non admin it returns basically the last post added for this post type:

```
$ticket_args = array(
   'post_type' => 'event_ticket',
   'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending'),
   'posts_per_page' => 1,
   'meta_query' => array(
      array(
         'key' => '_token',
         'value' => $_GET['token'],
      ),
   ),
);

$tickets = get_posts($ticket_args);
```

This works for all roles:

```
$ticket_args = array(
   'post_type' => 'event_ticket',
   'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending'),
   'posts_per_page' => 1,
   'meta_key' => '_token',
   'meta_value' => $_GET['token']
);

$tickets = get_posts($ticket_args);
```

More clarity:

The output of these 2 statements is NOT the same. As an admin user the results are as expected - the SINGLE 'event_ticket' post that contains the meta data '_token' that matches the query string param of 'token' is returned. As a NON admin the results are such that the LAST 'event_type' post is returned.

Does this have to do with caps or general WP permissions with respect to the meta_query function or do i have something wrong in meta_query args?

Comment: The given codes' outputs are equal to each other, there is not difference between them. Using meta_key, meta_value pair is just simplified form of meta_query.  I think you need to clarify what your final goal is, what you want to achieve. After that i might help

Comment: remove this "   'posts_per_page' => 1,
"

Comment: or set it to `'posts_per_page' => -1`

Comment: @ElvinHaci - well actually the output is NOT the same. As an admin user the results are as expected - the SINGLE event_ticket post that contains the meta data _token that matches the query string param of token is returned. As a NON admin (as the question states) the results are such that the LAST event_type post is returned (as also stated in the question).

Comment: DropHit, they are the same. If the output is not the same, it means you may have some user role based pre_get_posts filters somewhere else in website. Try to add suppress_filters parameter to your get_posts in order to stop additional custom filters

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the user roles using the below code :

```
$editor_query = new WP_User_Query(
    array(
        'role'              =>  array( 'editor', 'administrator' ),
        'meta_key'        => 'featured',
        'meta_value'      =>    'yes',
        'number'            =>  5
    )
);
```

Take the role from the above query the paste it in your code:

this line ->  'role'        =>  array( 'editor', 'administrator' ),

check if it works on not..mention your roles in the braces..